# FindOneAndUpdate not working correctly for me

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an application where I have a database of instructors with an array of ID's for classes.  When a new class is created, I'm trying to find the instructor's database entry and update the classID's array with the new class's ID. However, when I try and update it, nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
 data.classID = id;
new course(data).save((error) => {
    if(error){
        console.log('oops! Could not save course');
    } else {
        conn3.close();
    }
});
//update instructor's classID's variable in intructor database
instructor.findOne({"instructorEmail":data.Instructor}, (err,x)=>{
        var arr = x.classIDs;
        arr.push(id);
        instructor.findOneAndUpdate({"instructorEmail":data.Instructor},{$set:{classIDs: arr}});
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to append an id to the classIDs array you can use the $push operator.

```
instructor.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "instructorEmail": data.Instructor },
  { $push: { classIDS: id } },
  { new: true },
  (err, updatedDoc) => {
    // what ever u want to do with the updated document
  })
```